# Check in luggage transfer with different PNR but same company airlines

Tags: kuala-lumpur

I am a resident of Kolkata. I've booked a flight with Air Asia from DPS to KUL and KUL to CCU on 1st April 2024 with different PNR. We have already stayed 4 days in Kuala Lumpur before going to Bali, Indonesia, so I would like to know if our check-in luggage will be transferred automatically to the flights we have booked or do we have to get a transit visa and go through Immigration process and check in again? Kindly advise me what to do.

Comment: Probably yes (it is cheaper for airline), but experience say: *it depends* (probably on random stuffs), so you will know for sure only at airport (or if you have some written stuff for check-in staff, to force them to do it, so try to contact airline)

Comment: PS: do not write titles in UpperCase: it is ugly to read, and we tend to skip them. Let's the engine to format it for you (the site already know it is the title)

Answer (score 3):

With a full-fare airline your luggage would be tagged all the way, but with an LCC like AirAsia, probably not. Check with the airline in DPS ahead of time. But the good news is that for a year, starting Dember 1, 2023, you don't need a visa in Malaysia as an Indian citizen. So worst case scenario, you'll have to pass through Immigration, pick up your bags, and go upstairs to check in again and pass through security and Immigration.

I hope you have a few hours between flights.